# Can we reorder the sr.no while changing the cell position in Tableview in javafx?

Tags: javafx

[image]

I want to do that

If the cell position changed , the serial number would get re-order by itself sequentially while changing the position.is it possible for us while changing the cell position ...serial no column would reorder by itself..in TABLEVIEW

For example .. Suppose der are five rows as (**Fieldname**: F1 as **Sr.no**: 1,F2 as 2, F3 as 3, F4 as 4, F5 as 5)if f1 move to second place on click of down button then f1 srno would become 2 and f2 would be 1 dynamically after shifting the cell  ..

or if f5 move to upward position on click of up button, then srno for f5 would become 4 and f4 srno would become 5 ..

Kindly provide me a logic for that?

my code :

```
ReadOnlyIntegerProperty selectedIndex = tableupdateSpacee.getSelectionModel().selectedIndexProperty();

    upaction.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent evt) {
                int index = tableupdateSpacee.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
                // swap items
                tableupdateSpacee.getItems().add(index-1, tableupdateSpacee.getItems().remove(index));
                // select item at new position
                tableupdateSpacee.getSelectionModel().clearAndSelect(index-1);
                int a=colFieldSrno.getCellData(index);
                colFieldSrno.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("srno"));
                System.out.println("col serial number"+colFieldSrno.getCellData(index));

              //  tableupdateSpacee.getColumns().add(colFieldSrno.getCellData(index));




                tableupdateSpacee.setItems(modelUpdateSpace);
                tableupdateSpacee.refresh();
            }
        });

    downaction.setOnAction(evt -> {
        int index = tableupdateSpacee.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
        // swap items
        tableupdateSpacee.getItems().add(index+1, tableupdateSpacee.getItems().remove(index));
        // select item at new position
        tableupdateSpacee.getSelectionModel().clearAndSelect(index+1);


        tableupdateSpacee.refresh();
    });
```

Comment: So you want the `srNo` column just to display `(index + 1)` where `index` is the row number?

Comment: Yes if i move the row to downward position it should be index + 1 and for upward position it should be index - 1..

Comment: I think if you move it, its index will change, so you always want it to be `index+1`, no? You don't really need a property here at all.

Comment: int value1=Integer.parseInt(colFieldSrno.getCellData(index).toString());
I tried this one.. if i changing the row position , in console it show the srno properly .. that sr no i want to set in colFieldSrno(a column in tableview).. which i am not able to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this without having a `srNo` property in your table model at all. Just do:

```
TableColumn<S,Void> colFieldSrno = new TableColumn<>("Sr.No");
colFieldSrNo.setCellFactory(tc -> new TableCell<S,Void>() {
    @Override
    public void updateIndex(int index) {
        super.updateIndex(index);
        if (index < 0 || index >= tableupdateSpacee.getItems().size()) {
            setText(null);
        } else {
            setText(Integer.toString(index+1));
        }
    }
});
```

(here you need to replace `S` with whatever class you are using as your table model). Remove the `cellValueFactory` for the column entirely (the value is basically the index, it is not part of your table model), and remove the `srNo` property from the table model.

If you need the `srNo` property for other reasons (though you really shouldn't need it at all), then you just need to update it when you swap the values:

```
upaction.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent evt) {
        int index = tableupdateSpacee.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
        // swap items

        S item = tableupdateSpacee.getItems().get(index);
        S previousItem = tableUpdateSpacee.getItems().get(index - 1);
        previousItem.setSrNo(index);
        item.setSrNo(index-1);
        tableupdateSpacee.getItems().remove(index);
        tableupdateSpacee.getItems().add(index-1, item);
        // select item at new position
        tableupdateSpacee.getSelectionModel().clearAndSelect(index-1);
    }
});
```

and similarly for the `downaction`.

Comment: thank you for the reply.. will give a try and get back here..@James_D

Comment: Thanks a Lot .. you saved me..It's working perfectly..love you man :)

Comment: Hi, I want to reflect this changes in my database too. it just changing the position of cell in the tableview GUI.. but not reflecting that Changes in database... is there any way to change the position in database the way it is changing in tableview GUI.Thanks

Comment: @VikasShukla I'm not an SQL expert, by any means, but do rows in a database table even have an inherent defined notion of "order"? Can't you just use the second solution and then when you query the database order by `srNo`?